Leapp for Oracle Linux 7 to Oracle Linux 9 does not work
I am trying to Upgrade from Oracle Linux 7 to Oracle Linux 8. It does not work at all. I tried to solve dependecies issue by myself. Now I am stucked. I have this error code:
Warning: Packages marked by Leapp for install not found in repositories metadata: rpcgen
    Warning: Packages marked by Leapp for upgrade not found in repositories metadata: python2-leapp leapp-upgrade-el7toel8 leapp

And trying that:
sudo yum install leapp --enablerepo=ol7_leapp,ol7_latest,ol8_codeready_builder


    Transaction Summary
=====================================================================================================================
Install    265 Packages
Upgrade    384 Packages
Remove      42 Packages
Downgrade    6 Packages

Total size: 1.0 G
Total download size: 909 M
DNF will only download packages, install gpg keys, and check the transaction.
Downloading Packages:
[SKIPPED] libcroco-0.6.12-4.el8_2.1.x86_64.rpm: Already downloaded             
[SKIPPED] libzstd-1.4.4-1.0.1.el8.x86_64.rpm: Already downloaded               
[SKIPPED] brotli-1.0.6-3.el8.x86_64.rpm: Already downloaded                    
[SKIPPED] coreutils-common-8.30-15.0.1.el8.x86_64.rpm: Already downloaded      
[SKIPPED] crypto-policies-20230731-1.git3177e06.el8.noarch.rpm: Already downloaded
[SKIPPED] crypto-policies-scripts-20230731-1.git3177e06.el8.noarch.rpm: Already downloaded
[SKIPPED] dbus-common-1.12.8-26.0.1.el8.noarch.rpm: Already downloaded         
[SKIPPED] dbus-daemon-1.12.8-26.0.1.el8.x86_64.rpm: Already downloaded         
[SKIPPED] dbus-tools-1.12.8-26.0.1.el8.x86_64.rpm: Already downloaded          
[SKIPPED] device-mapper-multipath-0.8.4-41.el8.x86_64.rpm: Already downloaded  
[SKIPPED] device-mapper-multipath-libs-0.8.4-41.el8.x86_64.rpm: Already downloaded
[SKIPPED] dnf-plugins-core-4.0.21-25.0.1.el8.noarch.rpm: Already downloaded    
[SKIPPED] elfutils-debuginfod-client-0.190-2.el8.x86_64.rpm: Already downloaded
[SKIPPED] gdbm-libs-1.18-2.el8.x86_64.rpm: Already downloaded                  
[SKIPPED] glibc-all-langpacks-2.28-251.0.2.el8_10.2.x86_64.rpm: Already downloaded
[SKIPPED] glibc-gconv-extra-2.28-251.0.2.el8_10.2.x86_64.rpm: Already downloaded
[SKIPPED] gnupg2-smime-2.2.20-3.el8_6.x86_64.rpm: Already downloaded           
[SKIPPED] ima-evm-utils-1.3.2-12.el8.x86_64.rpm: Already downloaded            
[SKIPPED] libarchive-3.3.3-5.el8.x86_64.rpm: Already downloaded                
[SKIPPED] libevent-2.1.8-5.el8.x86_64.rpm: Already downloaded                  
[SKIPPED] libfdisk-2.32.1-46.0.1.el8.x86_64.rpm: Already downloaded            
[SKIPPED] libidn2-2.2.0-1.el8.x86_64.rpm: Already downloaded                   
[SKIPPED] libkcapi-1.4.0-2.0.1.el8.x86_64.rpm: Already downloaded              
[SKIPPED] libkcapi-hmaccalc-1.4.0-2.0.1.el8.x86_64.rpm: Already downloaded     
[SKIPPED] libksba-1.3.5-9.el8_7.x86_64.rpm: Already downloaded                 
[SKIPPED] libnghttp2-1.33.0-5.el8_9.x86_64.rpm: Already downloaded             
[SKIPPED] libnsl2-1.2.0-2.20180605git4a062cf.el8.x86_64.rpm: Already downloaded
[SKIPPED] libpsl-0.20.2-6.el8.x86_64.rpm: Already downloaded                   
[SKIPPED] libsecret-0.18.6-1.el8.x86_64.rpm: Already downloaded                
[SKIPPED] libsigsegv-2.11-5.el8.x86_64.rpm: Already downloaded                 
[SKIPPED] libssh-0.9.6-14.el8.x86_64.rpm: Already downloaded                   
[SKIPPED] libssh-config-0.9.6-14.el8.noarch.rpm: Already downloaded            
[SKIPPED] libtirpc-1.1.4-10.el8.x86_64.rpm: Already downloaded                 
[SKIPPED] libxcrypt-4.1.1-6.el8.x86_64.rpm: Already downloaded                 
[SKIPPED] lua-libs-5.3.4-12.el8.x86_64.rpm: Already downloaded                 
[SKIPPED] lz4-libs-1.8.3-3.el8_4.x86_64.rpm: Already downloaded                
[SKIPPED] memstrack-0.2.5-2.el8.x86_64.rpm: Already downloaded                 
[SKIPPED] mpfr-3.1.6-1.el8.x86_64.rpm: Already downloaded                      
[SKIPPED] npth-1.5-4.el8.x86_64.rpm: Already downloaded                        
[SKIPPED] openssl-pkcs11-0.4.10-3.el8.x86_64.rpm: Already downloaded           
[SKIPPED] pcre2-10.32-3.el8_6.x86_64.rpm: Already downloaded                   
[SKIPPED] platform-python-3.6.8-62.0.1.el8_10.x86_64.rpm: Already downloaded   
[SKIPPED] platform-python-pip-9.0.3-24.el8.noarch.rpm: Already downloaded      
[SKIPPED] platform-python-setuptools-39.2.0-7.el8.noarch.rpm: Already downloaded
[SKIPPED] publicsuffix-list-dafsa-20180723-1.el8.noarch.rpm: Already downloaded
[SKIPPED] python3-dateutil-2.6.1-6.el8.noarch.rpm: Already downloaded          
[SKIPPED] python3-dbus-1.2.4-15.el8.x86_64.rpm: Already downloaded             
[SKIPPED] python3-dnf-4.7.0-20.0.1.el8.noarch.rpm: Already downloaded          
[SKIPPED] python3-dnf-plugins-core-4.0.21-25.0.1.el8.noarch.rpm: Already downloaded
[SKIPPED] python3-gpg-1.13.1-12.el8.x86_64.rpm: Already downloaded             
[SKIPPED] python3-hawkey-0.63.0-19.0.1.el8.x86_64.rpm: Already downloaded      
[SKIPPED] python3-libcomps-0.1.18-1.el8.x86_64.rpm: Already downloaded         
[SKIPPED] python3-libdnf-0.63.0-19.0.1.el8.x86_64.rpm: Already downloaded      
[SKIPPED] python3-libs-3.6.8-62.0.1.el8_10.x86_64.rpm: Already downloaded      
[SKIPPED] python3-pip-wheel-9.0.3-24.el8.noarch.rpm: Already downloaded        
[SKIPPED] python3-rpm-4.14.3-31.0.1.el8.x86_64.rpm: Already downloaded         
[SKIPPED] python3-setuptools-wheel-39.2.0-7.el8.noarch.rpm: Already downloaded 
[SKIPPED] python3-six-1.11.0-8.el8.noarch.rpm: Already downloaded              
[SKIPPED] redhat-release-8.10-0.2.0.1.el8.x86_64.rpm: Already downloaded       
[SKIPPED] rpm-plugin-systemd-inhibit-4.14.3-31.0.1.el8.x86_64.rpm: Already downloaded
[SKIPPED] sqlite-libs-3.26.0-19.0.1.el8_9.x86_64.rpm: Already downloaded       
[SKIPPED] systemd-pam-239-82.0.2.el8.x86_64.rpm: Already downloaded            
[SKIPPED] systemd-udev-239-82.0.2.el8.x86_64.rpm: Already downloaded           
[SKIPPED] tpm2-tss-2.3.2-6.el8.x86_64.rpm: Already downloaded                  
[SKIPPED] trousers-lib-0.3.15-2.el8.x86_64.rpm: Already downloaded             
[SKIPPED] userspace-rcu-0.10.1-4.el8.x86_64.rpm: Already downloaded            
[SKIPPED] python3-unbound-1.16.2-5.el8_9.6.x86_64.rpm: Already downloaded      
[SKIPPED] unbound-libs-1.16.2-5.el8_9.6.x86_64.rpm: Already downloaded         
[SKIPPED] acl-2.2.53-3.el8.x86_64.rpm: Already downloaded                      
[SKIPPED] audit-libs-3.1.2-1.el8.x86_64.rpm: Already downloaded                
[SKIPPED] basesystem-11-5.el8.noarch.rpm: Already downloaded                   
[SKIPPED] bash-4.4.20-5.el8.x86_64.rpm: Already downloaded                     
[SKIPPED] bzip2-libs-1.0.6-26.el8.x86_64.rpm: Already downloaded               
[SKIPPED] ca-certificates-2023.2.60_v7.0.306-80.0.el8_8.noarch.rpm: Already downloaded
[SKIPPED] chkconfig-1.19.2-1.0.1.el8.x86_64.rpm: Already downloaded            
[SKIPPED] coreutils-8.30-15.0.1.el8.x86_64.rpm: Already downloaded             
[SKIPPED] cpio-2.12-11.el8.x86_64.rpm: Already downloaded                      
[SKIPPED] cracklib-2.9.6-15.el8.x86_64.rpm: Already downloaded                 
[SKIPPED] cracklib-dicts-2.9.6-15.el8.x86_64.rpm: Already downloaded           
[SKIPPED] cryptsetup-libs-2.3.7-7.el8.x86_64.rpm: Already downloaded           
[SKIPPED] curl-7.61.1-34.el8.x86_64.rpm: Already downloaded                    
[SKIPPED] cyrus-sasl-lib-2.1.27-6.el8_5.x86_64.rpm: Already downloaded         
[SKIPPED] dbus-1.12.8-26.0.1.el8.x86_64.rpm: Already downloaded                
[SKIPPED] dbus-glib-0.110-2.el8.x86_64.rpm: Already downloaded                 
[SKIPPED] dbus-libs-1.12.8-26.0.1.el8.x86_64.rpm: Already downloaded           
[SKIPPED] device-mapper-1.02.181-14.0.1.el8.x86_64.rpm: Already downloaded     
[SKIPPED] device-mapper-event-1.02.181-14.0.1.el8.x86_64.rpm: Already downloaded
[SKIPPED] device-mapper-event-libs-1.02.181-14.0.1.el8.x86_64.rpm: Already downloaded
[SKIPPED] device-mapper-libs-1.02.181-14.0.1.el8.x86_64.rpm: Already downloaded
[SKIPPED] device-mapper-persistent-data-0.9.0-7.el8.x86_64.rpm: Already downloaded
[SKIPPED] diffutils-3.6-6.el8.x86_64.rpm: Already downloaded                   
[SKIPPED] dnf-4.7.0-20.0.1.el8.noarch.rpm: Already downloaded                  
[SKIPPED] dnf-data-4.7.0-20.0.1.el8.noarch.rpm: Already downloaded             
[SKIPPED] dracut-049-233.git20240115.0.1.el8.x86_64.rpm: Already downloaded    
[SKIPPED] elfutils-default-yama-scope-0.190-2.el8.noarch.rpm: Already downloaded
[SKIPPED] elfutils-libelf-0.190-2.el8.x86_64.rpm: Already downloaded           
[SKIPPED] elfutils-libs-0.190-2.el8.x86_64.rpm: Already downloaded             
[SKIPPED] expat-2.2.5-13.0.1.el8_10.x86_64.rpm: Already downloaded             
[SKIPPED] file-5.33-26.el8.x86_64.rpm: Already downloaded                      
[SKIPPED] file-libs-5.33-26.el8.x86_64.rpm: Already downloaded                 
[SKIPPED] filesystem-3.8-6.el8.x86_64.rpm: Already downloaded                  
[SKIPPED] findutils-4.6.0-22.el8.x86_64.rpm: Already downloaded                
[SKIPPED] gawk-4.2.1-4.el8.x86_64.rpm: Already downloaded                      
[SKIPPED] gdbm-1.18-2.el8.x86_64.rpm: Already downloaded                       
[SKIPPED] gettext-0.19.8.1-17.el8.x86_64.rpm: Already downloaded               
[SKIPPED] gettext-libs-0.19.8.1-17.el8.x86_64.rpm: Already downloaded          
[SKIPPED] glib2-2.56.4-162.el8.x86_64.rpm: Already downloaded                  
[SKIPPED] glibc-2.28-251.0.2.el8_10.2.x86_64.rpm: Already downloaded           
[SKIPPED] glibc-common-2.28-251.0.2.el8_10.2.x86_64.rpm: Already downloaded    
[SKIPPED] gmp-6.1.2-11.el8.x86_64.rpm: Already downloaded                      
[SKIPPED] gnupg2-2.2.20-3.el8_6.x86_64.rpm: Already downloaded                 
[SKIPPED] gnutls-3.6.16-8.el8_9.3.x86_64.rpm: Already downloaded               
[SKIPPED] gpgme-1.13.1-12.el8.x86_64.rpm: Already downloaded                   
[SKIPPED] grep-3.1-6.el8.x86_64.rpm: Already downloaded                        
[SKIPPED] grub2-common-2.02-156.0.2.el8.noarch.rpm: Already downloaded         
[SKIPPED] grub2-tools-2.02-156.0.2.el8.x86_64.rpm: Already downloaded          
[SKIPPED] grub2-tools-minimal-2.02-156.0.2.el8.x86_64.rpm: Already downloaded  
[SKIPPED] grubby-8.40-49.0.1.el8.x86_64.rpm: Already downloaded                
[SKIPPED] gzip-1.9-13.el8_5.x86_64.rpm: Already downloaded                     
[SKIPPED] hardlink-1.3-6.el8.x86_64.rpm: Already downloaded                    
[SKIPPED] info-6.5-7.el8.x86_64.rpm: Already downloaded                        
[SKIPPED] json-c-0.13.1-3.el8.x86_64.rpm: Already downloaded                   
[SKIPPED] kbd-2.0.4-11.el8.x86_64.rpm: Already downloaded                      
[SKIPPED] kbd-legacy-2.0.4-11.el8.noarch.rpm: Already downloaded               
[SKIPPED] kbd-misc-2.0.4-11.el8.noarch.rpm: Already downloaded                 
[SKIPPED] keyutils-libs-1.5.10-9.el8.x86_64.rpm: Already downloaded            
[SKIPPED] kmod-25-20.0.1.el8.x86_64.rpm: Already downloaded                    
[SKIPPED] kmod-libs-25-20.0.1.el8.x86_64.rpm: Already downloaded               
[SKIPPED] kpartx-0.8.4-41.el8.x86_64.rpm: Already downloaded                   
[SKIPPED] krb5-libs-1.18.2-27.0.1.el8_10.x86_64.rpm: Already downloaded        
[SKIPPED] libacl-2.2.53-3.el8.x86_64.rpm: Already downloaded                   
[SKIPPED] libaio-0.3.112-1.el8.x86_64.rpm: Already downloaded                  
[SKIPPED] libassuan-2.5.1-3.el8.x86_64.rpm: Already downloaded                 
[SKIPPED] libattr-2.4.48-3.el8.x86_64.rpm: Already downloaded                  
[SKIPPED] libblkid-2.32.1-46.0.1.el8.x86_64.rpm: Already downloaded            
[SKIPPED] libcap-2.48-6.el8_9.x86_64.rpm: Already downloaded                   
[SKIPPED] libcap-ng-0.7.11-1.el8.x86_64.rpm: Already downloaded                
[SKIPPED] libcom_err-1.45.6-5.el8.x86_64.rpm: Already downloaded               
[SKIPPED] libcomps-0.1.18-1.el8.x86_64.rpm: Already downloaded                 
[SKIPPED] libcurl-7.61.1-34.el8.x86_64.rpm: Already downloaded                 
[SKIPPED] libdb-5.3.28-42.0.1.el8_4.x86_64.rpm: Already downloaded             
[SKIPPED] libdb-utils-5.3.28-42.0.1.el8_4.x86_64.rpm: Already downloaded       
[SKIPPED] libdnf-0.63.0-19.0.1.el8.x86_64.rpm: Already downloaded              
[SKIPPED] libedit-3.1-23.20170329cvs.el8.x86_64.rpm: Already downloaded        
[SKIPPED] libffi-3.1-24.el8.x86_64.rpm: Already downloaded                     
[SKIPPED] libgcc-8.5.0-22.0.1.el8_10.x86_64.rpm: Already downloaded            
[SKIPPED] libgcrypt-1.8.5-7.el8_6.x86_64.rpm: Already downloaded               
[SKIPPED] libgomp-8.5.0-22.0.1.el8_10.x86_64.rpm: Already downloaded           
[SKIPPED] libgpg-error-1.31-1.el8.x86_64.rpm: Already downloaded               
[SKIPPED] libmodulemd-2.13.0-1.el8.x86_64.rpm: Already downloaded              
[SKIPPED] libmount-2.32.1-46.0.1.el8.x86_64.rpm: Already downloaded            
[SKIPPED] libpwquality-1.4.4-6.el8.x86_64.rpm: Already downloaded              
[SKIPPED] librepo-1.14.2-5.el8.x86_64.rpm: Already downloaded                  
[SKIPPED] libreport-filesystem-2.9.5-15.0.4.el8.x86_64.rpm: Already downloaded 
[SKIPPED] libseccomp-2.5.2-1.el8.x86_64.rpm: Already downloaded                
[SKIPPED] libselinux-2.9-8.el8.x86_64.rpm: Already downloaded                  
[SKIPPED] libsemanage-2.9-9.el8_6.x86_64.rpm: Already downloaded               
[SKIPPED] libsepol-2.9-3.el8.x86_64.rpm: Already downloaded                    
[SKIPPED] libsmartcols-2.32.1-46.0.1.el8.x86_64.rpm: Already downloaded        
[SKIPPED] libsolv-0.7.20-6.el8.x86_64.rpm: Already downloaded                  
[SKIPPED] libstdc++-8.5.0-22.0.1.el8_10.x86_64.rpm: Already downloaded         
[SKIPPED] libtasn1-4.13-4.el8_7.x86_64.rpm: Already downloaded                 
[SKIPPED] libunistring-0.9.9-3.el8.x86_64.rpm: Already downloaded              
[SKIPPED] libusbx-1.0.23-4.el8.x86_64.rpm: Already downloaded                  
[SKIPPED] libutempter-1.1.6-14.el8.x86_64.rpm: Already downloaded              
[SKIPPED] libuuid-2.32.1-46.0.1.el8.x86_64.rpm: Already downloaded             
[SKIPPED] libverto-0.3.2-2.el8.x86_64.rpm: Already downloaded                  
[SKIPPED] libxml2-2.9.7-18.el8_10.1.x86_64.rpm: Already downloaded             
[SKIPPED] libyaml-0.1.7-5.el8.x86_64.rpm: Already downloaded                   
[SKIPPED] lvm2-2.03.14-14.0.1.el8.x86_64.rpm: Already downloaded               
[SKIPPED] lvm2-libs-2.03.14-14.0.1.el8.x86_64.rpm: Already downloaded          
[SKIPPED] ncurses-6.1-10.20180224.el8.x86_64.rpm: Already downloaded           
[SKIPPED] ncurses-base-6.1-10.20180224.el8.noarch.rpm: Already downloaded      
[SKIPPED] ncurses-libs-6.1-10.20180224.el8.x86_64.rpm: Already downloaded      
[SKIPPED] nettle-3.4.1-7.el8.x86_64.rpm: Already downloaded                    
[SKIPPED] openldap-2.4.46-18.el8.x86_64.rpm: Already downloaded                
[SKIPPED] openssl-1.1.1k-12.el8_9.x86_64.rpm: Already downloaded               
[SKIPPED] openssl-libs-1.1.1k-12.el8_9.x86_64.rpm: Already downloaded          
[SKIPPED] oraclelinux-release-8.10-1.0.7.el8.x86_64.rpm: Already downloaded    
[SKIPPED] os-prober-1.74-9.0.1.el8.x86_64.rpm: Already downloaded              
[SKIPPED] p11-kit-0.23.22-2.el8.x86_64.rpm: Already downloaded                 
[SKIPPED] p11-kit-trust-0.23.22-2.el8.x86_64.rpm: Already downloaded           
[SKIPPED] pam-1.3.1-33.0.2.el8.x86_64.rpm: Already downloaded                  
[SKIPPED] pcre-8.42-6.el8.x86_64.rpm: Already downloaded                       
[SKIPPED] pigz-2.4-4.el8.x86_64.rpm: Already downloaded                        
[SKIPPED] popt-1.18-1.el8.x86_64.rpm: Already downloaded                       
[SKIPPED] procps-ng-3.3.15-14.0.1.el8.x86_64.rpm: Already downloaded           
[SKIPPED] readline-7.0-10.el8.x86_64.rpm: Already downloaded                   
[SKIPPED] rpm-4.14.3-31.0.1.el8.x86_64.rpm: Already downloaded                 
[SKIPPED] rpm-build-libs-4.14.3-31.0.1.el8.x86_64.rpm: Already downloaded      
[SKIPPED] rpm-libs-4.14.3-31.0.1.el8.x86_64.rpm: Already downloaded            
[SKIPPED] sed-4.5-5.el8.x86_64.rpm: Already downloaded                         
[SKIPPED] setup-2.12.2-9.el8.noarch.rpm: Already downloaded                    
[SKIPPED] shadow-utils-4.6-22.el8.x86_64.rpm: Already downloaded               
[SKIPPED] shared-mime-info-1.9-4.el8.x86_64.rpm: Already downloaded            
[SKIPPED] systemd-239-82.0.2.el8.x86_64.rpm: Already downloaded                
[SKIPPED] systemd-libs-239-82.0.2.el8.x86_64.rpm: Already downloaded           
[SKIPPED] trousers-0.3.15-2.el8.x86_64.rpm: Already downloaded                 
[SKIPPED] tzdata-2024a-1.0.1.el8.noarch.rpm: Already downloaded                
[SKIPPED] util-linux-2.32.1-46.0.1.el8.x86_64.rpm: Already downloaded          
[SKIPPED] which-2.21-20.el8.x86_64.rpm: Already downloaded                     
[SKIPPED] xz-5.2.4-4.el8_6.x86_64.rpm: Already downloaded                      
[SKIPPED] xz-libs-5.2.4-4.el8_6.x86_64.rpm: Already downloaded                 
[SKIPPED] zlib-1.2.11-25.el8.x86_64.rpm: Already downloaded                    
[SKIPPED] libxkbcommon-0.9.1-1.el8.x86_64.rpm: Already downloaded              
[SKIPPED] pinentry-1.1.0-2.el8.x86_64.rpm: Already downloaded                  
[SKIPPED] xkeyboard-config-2.28-1.el8.noarch.rpm: Already downloaded           
(208/652): libcgroup-0.41-19.el8.x86_64.rpm     646 kB/s |  70 kB     00:00    
(209/652): fuse3-libs-3.3.0-19.0.1.el8.x86_64.r 849 kB/s |  95 kB     00:00    
(210/652): NetworkManager-initscripts-updown-1.  12 MB/s | 143 kB     00:00    
(211/652): atk-2.28.1-1.el8.x86_64.rpm           13 MB/s | 272 kB     00:00    
(212/652): authselect-1.2.6-2.el8.x86_64.rpm    8.9 MB/s | 147 kB     00:00    
(213/652): bluez-libs-5.63-1.el8.x86_64.rpm     4.9 MB/s | 114 kB     00:00    
(214/652): crda-3.18_2020.04.29-1.el8.noarch.rp 2.0 MB/s |  24 kB     00:00    
(215/652): dejavu-sans-mono-fonts-2.35-7.el8.no  15 MB/s | 447 kB     00:00    
(216/652): dhcp-client-4.3.6-50.el8_10.x86_64.r  25 MB/s | 317 kB     00:00    
(217/652): dracut-live-049-233.git20240115.0.1. 7.4 MB/s |  74 kB     00:00    
[...]
(651/652): xfsprogs-5.4.0-1.0.5.el8.x86_64.rpm   20 MB/s | 1.1 MB     00:00    
(652/652): scap-security-guide-0.1.73-1.0.1.el8 1.7 MB/s | 6.7 MB     00:03    
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Total                                            46 MB/s | 909 MB     00:19     
Running transaction check
Transaction check succeeded.
Running transaction test
The downloaded packages were saved in cache until the next successful transaction.
You can remove cached packages by executing 'dnf clean packages'.

STDERR:
Warning: Packages marked by Leapp for install not found in repositories metadata: rpcgen
Warning: Packages marked by Leapp for upgrade not found in repositories metadata: python2-leapp leapp-upgrade-el7toel8 leapp
RPM: warning: Generating 6 missing index(es), please wait...
Error: Transaction test error:
  file /usr/sbin/pidof from install of procps-ng-3.3.15-14.0.1.el8.x86_64 conflicts with file from package sysvinit-tools-2.88-14.dsf.el7.x86_64
  file /usr/bin/last from install of util-linux-2.32.1-46.0.1.el8.x86_64 conflicts with file from package sysvinit-tools-2.88-14.dsf.el7.x86_64
  file /usr/bin/mesg from install of util-linux-2.32.1-46.0.1.el8.x86_64 conflicts with file from package sysvinit-tools-2.88-14.dsf.el7.x86_64
  file /usr/bin/wall from install of util-linux-2.32.1-46.0.1.el8.x86_64 conflicts with file from package sysvinit-tools-2.88-14.dsf.el7.x86_64
  file /usr/share/man/man1/last.1.gz from install of util-linux-2.32.1-46.0.1.el8.x86_64 conflicts with file from package sysvinit-tools-2.88-14.dsf.el7.x86_64
  file /usr/share/man/man1/mesg.1.gz from install of util-linux-2.32.1-46.0.1.el8.x86_64 conflicts with file from package sysvinit-tools-2.88-14.dsf.el7.x86_64
  file /usr/share/man/man1/wall.1.gz from install of util-linux-2.32.1-46.0.1.el8.x86_64 conflicts with file from package sysvinit-tools-2.88-14.dsf.el7.x86_64



============================================================
                       END OF ERRORS                        
============================================================


Debug output written to /var/log/leapp/leapp-upgrade.log

============================================================
                           REPORT                           
============================================================

A report has been generated at /var/log/leapp/leapp-report.json
A report has been generated at /var/log/leapp/leapp-report.txt

============================================================
                       END OF REPORT                        
============================================================

Answerfile has been generated at /var/log/leapp/answerfile

P.S. This post didn't help me: leapp does not want to upgrade Oracle Linux from 7.9 to 8.x

I am a newbie on Oracle Linux: Would it be possible to do a distro-sync / upgrade in a chroot environment from Oracle Linux 8 or better, Oracle Linux 9? Would this work?
